# How is the performance of many small Lua scripts versus a few large ones?

Tags: performance, lua

I am planning to use Lua as a scripting language for objects in a game I am working on. However, each object in game (of which there may be up to 1000) will have it's own script attached. On the bright side, each script would be very short (less than 256 instructions).

In such a case, would the performance be slow and the memory usage high relative to a single large script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably your program will have an init stage in which you "compile" each script to a chunk (only once), and a loop stage when the objects evolve i.e. you call the chunks as many times as desired. In that case, performance is same for both strategies, in loop stage. In init stage, there might be a small difference:

- If the scripts are stored in memory then the "init" stage could be faster with the one big script if the bottleneck is calling the loadstring function (possible if the scripts are really small).
- If scripts stored in files then reading 1000 tiny files might be slower than reading 1 file a 1000 times larger, but I would guess this to be true only if filesystem read access is the bottleneck (versus, say, compilation into a chunk).

However you typically would not worry about the "init" of the game (during which the 1000 scripts get compiled), just the run loop. If this is your case, I would recommend using the one-script-per-object strategy. The other advantage of the script-per-object approach is that you could eventually decide to only compile scripts for objects when needed, which is not necessarily immediately after init. For instance, maybe some object become active only under certain conditions; then compile the script only when the condition is first satisfied, and cache the chunk so you don't have to compile again (for that object).

Update:

You can use the chunk anywhere, it is just a Lua reference to a chunk of Lua code. You can even "parametrize" the chunk via the "..." keyword, so if your chunk is the multiline string:

```
local arg1, arg2 = ...
print(arg1, arg2)
```

and you bind it to a variable 'test' then you can call the chunk with different values for the parameters:

```
test(1, 2)
test('a', 'b')
```

will yield

```
1   2
a   b
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One further question: if you have a single chunk but multiple objects using that chunk, would you be able to repeat the chunk across all objects or would you be required to compile a chunk / copy it per instance? (Assuming a reference implementation)

Comment: Updated to answer extension.